# Is there an Function the get amount of lines in a filestream in C?

Tags: c, file

I am making a Homework right now in which I have to read a .csv - file with different Lottery-tips. Right now I need to check if the tip number really exists/if it is valid. (It is valid if the number is greater or equal 0 and if it is smaller or equal to the biggest tip number).

This is what I would've made:

```
bool is_tip_number_valid(int tip_number){
    if(tip_number < 0){
        return false;
    }
}
```

of course in the if-condition I need to check if the tip-number is bigger than the amount of lines in the csv. 
Is there any way I can get the lines in the csv? 
I thought I could just run through the whole filestream with a loop, but that would need very much time, because the csv has around 500000 Lines.

Comment: Nops, there isn't a function for that, just count the number of `fgets` until the files is completely readed.

Comment: If each line is a fixed size, you can calculate the number based on that and total file size. Otherwise, you have to read the file and count them as you go.

Comment: Personally, if what you're doing involves a lot of lookups of different lines of the file, I'd throw it into a sqlite database, add appropriate indexes, and query that instead.